# Use of base_library.zip file in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, autopy

I created a PyQt application and then made it's .exe file using `auto-py-to-exe`. I am observing that it has created a `base_library.zip` file inside my directory. I want to know it's purpose and should I unzip this file or not?

I am using Python 3, PyQt4 and windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auto-py-to-exe` creates a `base_library.zip` file when selected "One Directory". One shouldn't try to unzip this file. Just leave it as it is.